# How to disable form submit button if the username already exits in database ? (by js, ajax, php(laravel))

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new js learner, and I am trying to build a form. in the form I want to check if the input username is already taken or exists and I have done this by laravel controller and lil JS code but I want to HIDE the submit button if the input username is already exists in the database. so how do I do this? please anybody

This is my JS code

```
<script type="">

$function get_user_name(id, result) {
  var id = $(id).val();
  $.get("<?php echo e(url('home/get_user_name')) ?>/" + id,
  function (data) {
    $(result).html(data);
  });
}
</script>
```

Controller =>

```
**and 
controller =** 

public function get_user_name()
  {
     $username = request()->segment(3);
    $user = DB::table('users')
    ->select('username')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->count();

    $nam = "username already taken";

    if ($user >0) {
      return $nam;
    }else{
    }
  }
```

html form =>

```
    <span id="username_rs" style="color: green; font-weight: bold"></span>//showing the message here,

<input id="username" name="username"

           onchange="checkem('#username', '#username_rs')" >


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Register') }}
          </button>
```

route =>

```
Route::get('/home/get_user_name/{username}', 'HomeController@get_user_name')->name('checkun');
```

And url look like =>

```
http://localhost/home/get_user_name/{input username}
```

My code is showing if the username is taken or not, but I want to hide the submit button if the username is taken or exists in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return like this:

```
**and 
controller =** 

public function get_user_name()
  {
     $username = request()->segment(3);
    $user = DB::table('users')
    ->select('username')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->count();

    if ($user >0) {
      return Response::json(array("found"=>"yes", "message"=>"Username is already taken"));       
    }else{
       return Response::json(array("found"=>"no", "message"=>"Something happens wrong"));
    }
  }
```

Your Script code looks like:

```
$function get_user_name(id, result) {
  var id = $(id).val();
  $.get("<?php echo e(url('home/get_user_name')) ?>/" + id,
  function (data) {
     if (data.found == 'yes)
     {
        $("#submit_btn").css("display","none")
     }
  });
}
```

HTML code looks like:

```
<span id="username_rs" style="color: green; font-weight: bold"></span>//showing the message here,

<input id="username" name="username"

           onchange="checkem('#username', '#username_rs')" >


<button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Register') }}
          </button>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but its showing controller error =>   Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::$output ,, How can i use output in the controller?

Comment: I have updated the code. Would you please check it again?

Comment: It also help me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function get_user_name(id, result) {
  var id = $(id).val();
  $.get("<?php echo e(url('home/get_user_name')) ?>/" + id,
  function (data) {
    //check if we get the message: username already taken
    if(data) {
      $(result).html(data);
      $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable button
      $('form').bind('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();}); //disable form
    } else {
      $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled'); //enable button
      $('form').unbind('submit'); //enable form
    }
  });
}
```